# Pandas printing more cells than necessary

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to print the content of an excel file using Python. 
Here you are my file: 
[image: Excel file] 
I used the following code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', False)

path = "C:\\Users\\jackv\\Desktop\\excel\\"

def getFilesInDirectory():
    return [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

def getDataFromFile(excelFile):
    fullpath = path+excelFile
    return pd.read_excel(fullpath)

filesInDirectory = getFilesInDirectory()
print(getDataFromFile(filesInDirectory[0]))
```

The output I get has more rows and columns as you can see here: 
[image: output]

I would like to have just 3 columns and 11 rows as my output. 
How can I get rid of the empty cells?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your `pd.read_excel()` function as such:

```
pd.read_excel(fullpath,
              header=1,
              use_cols=[A:C])
```

This will tell the function to use the first row as headers, and it should only consider the first three columns for input.

Comment: This is quite right, the thing that worked for me is: `pd.read_excel(fullpath, header=2, usecols=['Data', 'Nome', 'Controvalore Attuale'])`